# mongoDB: aggregate dynamic/multiple fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to convert a collection with nested documents to a model tree structure with parent references. So this is how my structure looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "sdaGREsfRdfGdFdwG",
    "docTitle" : "Document 1",
    "group" : [
        {
            "id" : "cdPhkTpMXi8z6TqMT"
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "id" : "Nkspf5kKfPo3axeJA",
                    "some" : "data",
                    "other" : "things",
                    "and" : "so on",    
                },
                {
                    "id" : "vyjgkuNXRN9KkCd5o",
                    "some" : "data",
                    "any" : "thing",    
                }
            ],

        },
        {
            "id" : "TuibXPe5qMvqdMW6q"
            "title" : "title 2",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "id" : "f5L5zsSNRSQKWoAXL",
                    "some" : "data",

                },
                {
                    "id" : "Ca8ncFgq83RoeD8he",
                    "some" : "data",
                    "other" : "things",

                },
            ],

        }
    ]
}
```

To get the data elements (which are children of the group-elements), I do this:

```
db.myCol.aggregate([{$unwind:"$group"}, 
                {$unwind:"$group.data"}, 
                {$project:{_id:"$group.data.id", some:"$group.data.some", 
                           parent:"$group.id", type:{$literal:"element"}}}])
```

My problem is to get all fields of the data object as the structure of each element differs. There are differnt fields or different number of fields, as the content is dynamic. In the code above I take explicit the field `same`, but this doesn't really help. I would like to use the complete content and add the fields `type` and `parent`.

*result*

```
{
    "_id" : "Nkspf5kKfPo3axeJA",
    "some" : "data",
    "other" : "things",
    "and" : "so on",
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "cdPhkTpMXi8z6TqMT"
},
{
    "_id" : "vyjgkuNXRN9KkCd5o",
    "some" : "data",
    "any" : "thing",
},
{
    "_id" : "f5L5zsSNRSQKWoAXL",
    "some" : "data",
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "TuibXPe5qMvqdMW6q"      
},
{
    "_id" : "Ca8ncFgq83RoeD8he",
    "some" : "data",
    "other" : "things",
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "TuibXPe5qMvqdMW6q"  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question you mentioned that you don't know the structure of `data` element, so to keep `data` as an array changed your output structure. Here, I post the answer but it not exactly your expected output, but solve the problem of `data` array dynamic fields using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in aggregation.

```
db.myCol.aggregate({
    "$project": {
        "results": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$group",
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "parent": "$$el.id",
                    "type": {
                        "$literal": "element"
                    },
                    "data": "$$el.data"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$results"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "results": {
            "$push": "$results"
        }
    }
}).pretty()
```

If you `unwind` again before `group` like `{$wunwind:$results.data}` then you will get all `data` array values.